# contruct a inductive limit without index set be directed which is the union of the set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

This is a problem from commutative algebra and algebraic geometry.
It states as follows:

Let $X$ be a set and $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ a family of subsets in $X$

Abandoning the condition on the directness of index sets(ie, for any indices $i$,$j$, there is an index $k$, such that $i$,$j$ $\le$ $k$) for inductive systems, interpret $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ as an inductive system satisfying $$\underrightarrow{\lim}U_i=\cup_{i\in I}U_i,$$
I use the inclusion  as preorder on I and we don't assume it is directed, since $U_{i}$ be arbitrary subset. However, when I want to show that there exist a unique $g:\cup_{i\in I}U_i \to H$ for a given $H,gi:U_{i}\to H$ satisfy the universal property, I want to define $g(u_i)=g_i(u_i)$ for $u_i\in U_i$. However, I face a well defined problem,that is $g_j(u_i)=g_i(u_i)$ for $u_i \in U_i\cap U_j $. The problem will be $\emptyset \neq U_i \cap U_j \subsetneq U_i,U_j$ I think the problem is I need to define a "good" preorder, can someone help me?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It works out if you take there to be a unique map $U_i\to U_j$ iff $U_i\subseteq U_j$, i.e. you do take the partial order on $\{U_i\}$ corresponding to inclusion. Then your well-definedness problem disappears. Note that this system is then not direct, because there may be $U$ and $V$ such that there is no $W$ in the system for which $U\subseteq W$ and $V\subseteq W$.

Comment: @DaniëlApol could you explain  what this sentence mean:  to be a unique map……if  $U_i$ contained in $U_j$ does this is for preorder or g ,if it is g ,how can I define g  explicitly for $u_i$ by this condition？ thanks

Comment: You are given a collection $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of subsets, and want to define some arrows between them in order for their colimit to be $\cup_{i\in I} U_i$. I propose to let there be an inclusion arrow $U_i\to U_j$ precisely when $U_i\subseteq U_j$. If you then have a given $H$ and maps $g_i\colon U_i\to H$ _that commute with these maps between the $U_k$_, then this means that $g_i(u_i)=g_j(u_i)$ if $u_i\in U_i$ and $U_i\subseteq U_j$. Therefore, your definition of $g\colon\cup_{i\in I}U_i\to H$ by $g(u_i)=g_i(u_i)$ if $u_i\in U_i$ does not face any problems with wll-definedness.

Comment: Oh wait, I see the problem now: you don't know that there are ''enough'' subsets $U_i$ in your family to cover the intersection of two subsets.  I'm sorry, I missed that part. My solution only works in this case where you have enough subsets in the above sense.

Comment: @DaniëlApol,you re right ,in fact. Wow ,this is a good journey.I find that we can define subcategory, of set  instead, to make well defined  satisfied.